# updateMany to insert an object into an array: unexpected token

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

An example of a record:

```
{name: anUserInfo.name, userid: anUserInfo.userid, deviceToken: anUserInfo.deviceToken, email: anUserInfo.email, requesters: [], friends: [], rejects: []}
```

There is "Unexpected Token ." error at "requesters.push".

Basically, I need to insert `requesterID` into the `requesters` array from all records with `email` is `email`.  Any ideas?

```
  var email = myUserInfo.email;  // friend's email
  var reqeusterID = myUserInfo.userid;   // requester 's id'

  var collection = myDb.collection('UsersInfoObject');
  collection.updateMany(
    {email: email},  //critieria
    {
      $set: {requesters.push(reqeusterID)}
    },function (err, numUpdated) {
    console.log('kCommand kFriendRequest updateMany');
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.
If you want to add unique value in requesters, use $addToSet

```
collection.updateMany(
    {email:"sddfds@gmail.com"},
    {$push:{requesters:reqeusterID}}
)
```

Comment: Good to know the $addToSet, I was wondering about that.  Thanks.

Comment: $addToSet doesnt work with updateMany(). No idea why.
It show this error with Typescript 

TS2322: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.